# Uno platform: Debug.Writeline for Wasm doesn't output anything

Tags: debugging, uno-platform

I'm trying to figure out how to debug Uno Platform apps for the Wasm target. Breakpoints don't work and I have not figured out how to get debug output to work, either.

For example, I have in App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
  ...
  Debug.WriteLine("OnStart.begin");
}
```

and

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

But noting appears in the "output" window when I run the app. Is there a different logging technique I should use ?

EDIT

I followed the instructions, mentioned by Jerome, and opened the debug panel for my app. However, there were no further instructions displayed at that point and I didn't see any scripts that seemed to resemble my app. See attached screenshot. What should I be looking for ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Debug.WriteLine` is not supported on WebAssembly at this point.

You can use `Console.WriteLine()` instead, or use the logging facilities provided by the default Uno app template (using `this.Log().Debug(...)`, and the [ConfigureLoggers][1] method)

Comment: Both of these statements build, but I'm not seeing any output in the VS "output" window. I have my ConfigureFilters set exactly as shown in your link, above.  Even running UWP outputs nothing.

Comment: The underlying issue is how to debug Wasm projects. Breakpoints don't work (and I think I read that is correct) so I think writing debug output is probably the next best thing.

Comment: Indeed, debugging in the VS output is something that has yet to be provided by the .NET team. As for the debugging, make sure to follow this: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno.wasm.bootstrap#how-to-use-the-visual-studio-2019-debugger. And for UWP, only `Debug.WriteLine` works, not `Console.WriteLine`, which is where having loggers setup properly help.

Comment: Well, no luck yet. See EDIT in the OP. In the meantime, I'll take another look at logging.

Comment: @PeriHartman The output after using `Console.WriteLine()` will appear into the "Console" tab

Comment: "Console" window ? Searching online, apparently there used to be a console window but I can't find anything current about it. I have tabs for "command", "Immediate", and "output." In the debug menu there are some more things, but no "console". Could you elaborate, please ?

Comment: Didn't he mean F12 the development tools in Chrome? I  would be leaning much further into saying that. Though nothing appears there for me either.